# pandas column value and variable values string concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

url="https://nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O"

headers = { "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78"}

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df1=pd.DataFrame().from_records(r['data'])
df2=df1[['symbol','dayHigh','dayLow','lastPrice','yearHigh','yearLow','previousClose','change','pChange']]
df2=df2.sort_values(['symbol'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
nifty1=df2.round(2)
nifty1
dt1 = '01-01-2020'
dt2 = '11-01-2020'
```

Generating following output

```
    symbol  dayHigh dayLow  lastPrice   yearHigh    yearLow previousClose   change  pChange
0   ACC 1525    1487.25 1510.8  1769.05 1326    1486.15 24.65   1.66
1   ADANIENT    213 205.9   210.5   221.5   113 208 2.50    1.20
2   ADANIPORTS  394.3   390 391.3   430.6   292.1   391.8   -0.50   -0.13
...
```

I have following string for

```
https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=XXXX&series=["EQ"]&from=fromdt&to=todt
```

I want to replace XXXX by nifty1['symbol'] column, preferably without space and fromdt and todt with dt1 and dt2

eg.

```
https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ACC&series=["EQ"]&from=01-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIENT&series=["EQ"]&from=01-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIPORTS&series=["EQ"]&from=01-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
```

and store into new dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do using [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
new_df = (df['symbol']
          .apply(lambda x: f'https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol={x}&series=["EQ"]&from=fromdt&to=todt')
          .to_frame())
```

Comment: thanks a lot  but it is having 2 issues 1) I have to also replace fromdt and todt with variable values e.g. from=01-01-2020&to=11-01-2020 and secondly it is not left justified

Comment: modification of code solved the first issue from={dt1}&to={dt2}

Comment: I just used the string as is given in the question, hope it helped.

Comment: surely it help Thanks a lot